# Problem with cassandra-connector at "load()"

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I downloaded succesfully this connector: `com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.1`

And when I try to load the information with this line:

```
data = sparkSession.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="tbthesis", 
keyspace="test").load()
```

I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: Py4JJavaError
An error occurred while calling o48.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra. 
Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

Any ideas besides what the error suggests about "Look for another connector"? Indeed, this is the connector which several professionals have suggested me to use, hence it most be something else I think.

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra-spark-read-ops

Comment: Thanks, I think this link you share will be very helpful once I solve the problem, somehow the problem is in the method load() only, seems to be somthing else

Comment: package should be registered via `--packages` or via `--jars`

Comment: Mmm, that's new for me, I have used --packages so far, I will try --jars and see the difference

Comment: --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.1 works fine,

Comment: --jars com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.1 doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved, I had to download:

```
--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:2.5.1
```

which is the right connector for my scala version: 2.12.10

Thank you all for your support!